# Intel wireless 7260 does not work on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, intel-wireless

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo x240 laptop which has a Intel Wireless 7260. I don't know why the network connection does not show anything. Actually nothing comes up; no internet connection.
Could someone help me with the steps to figure it out?

Comment: The sections labeled "Devices, Drivers, Connections,Config Files, Commands" at the top of this page have a few walk throughs on how to trouble shoot wifi connection issues: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel in 12.04 doesn't include the driver for your card, so you'll need to grab that first:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.15-rc1/backports-3.15-rc1-1.tar.gz
tar xzf backports-3.15-rc1-1.tar.gz
cd backports-3.15-rc1-1
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Then, you'll need the firmware for your card:

```
wget http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.24.8.0.tgz
tar xzf iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.24.8.0.tgz
sudo cp iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.15.8.0/iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode /lib/firmware/
```

And finally, reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

(By the way, you just did a fresh install of 12.04? You know that 14.04 is out, right?)

Comment: Thanks..I'll check it now. Yes! I need to write a code which only works with 12.04! :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the driver or any packages. The kernel is not able to load the driver.

The solution that worked for me is that I upgraded the Kernel to 4.2.042 and rebooted. I had problem with ethernet as well as wifi. This one upgrade solved both the issues without installing any additional packages.

Kernel 4.0 onwards comes with built in support for multiple hardwares. Ubuntu officially doesn't support 4.2.042 kernel for Ubuntu 12.04. You can install the kernel of ubuntu 14.04 onto 12.04. After exhausting all the solutions provided by others I finally got it working with this update.

PC Model is Dell Optiplex 5040.

These kernel packages are upward compatible from ubuntu server 12.04 to ubuntu 16.04.