# Ubuntu 12.04 Intel Ethernet & Wireless need drivers

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel, acer, iwlwifi

Neither wireless or ethernet is working on my Acer TravelMate p645-MG Ubuntu 12.04 laptop. I'm currently using a USB Wifi dongle, but I would like to get the drivers working.
I found this post: [Intel wireless 7260 does not work on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473174/intel-wireless-7260-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-12-04/473185#473185?newreg=54873ba41e0d4b09b7ac744cbf24b4e2)

I downloaded the latest iwlwifi-7260 driver (I got 25.222.9.0, unlike the 22.24.8.0 in the answer) and put the .ucode file in /lib/firmware/ and rebooted.
I skipped the first step that looked like downloading and compiling a whole new Kernel because when I looked at the driver download it said it works with 3.14.9+, and I have 3.2.0-69.

Also, could someone please tell me how I can get drivers for the Intel I218-LM?

lspci -nn | grep Wireless

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
```

lspci -nn | grep Ethernet

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM [8086:155a] (rev 04)
```

uname -r

```
3.2.0-69-generic
```

Comment: I am not familiar with your specific hardware, but usually, things work the other way around. You have a particular kernel and you load a driver module with something like insmod to get it to work initially. The trick is that driver modules are usually (always?) compiled with the header files for your exact kernel. So, usually, you download the driver, install the header files for your kernel, and then recompile/make the driver so it matches your kernel.

Comment: If you only have access to binary driver modules, newer isn't necessarily better. You have to choose the one which matches your kernel. You may also want to take a look at the output of `lsmod` to see which relevant drivers are currently being loaded and also take a look at `dmesg | less` output to see what error messages you may be getting from those modules.

Comment: I would try booting Ubuntu 14.04 and see if your hardware works with a newer kernel.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I'll try that if I don't get any good answers.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and that resolved the problem. Should I delete the question, or just leave it up?